# Push notification issues in C# for iPhone?

Tags: c#, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have used the push notification in my app and I have used our own server, it communicates with the apple server. But the problem is, the notifications are queued in the apple server and it doesn't send any notification to the device.

In server side, they are using C# for push notification services and they have traced the value in that method "service.QueueNotification(alertNotification)". So always the notifications are in the QUEUE and it doesn't send any notification to the device.

Comment: Are you using Moon-APNS code for push notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, i am testing the notification in the adhoc mode. The problem is, my developer account was expired so that the notification always in the queue from the apple server and it doesn't send any notification to the device. After that i have used some different valid accounts and it work's fine now.

Thanks!